# QUERY to find matches across a range

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I would like to count the total occurrences of series that have "Action" as a main genre and then "Magic" as one of it's other tags. Currently I have:

```
=Query(A:BM,"Select Count(L) where (L='Action')")
```

L being the row where the main genre is listed. Following that row (M:BM) are a bunch of tags. Is it possible to use query to tally that up? Something like:

```
=Query(A:BM,"Select Count(L) where (L='Action') and (M:BM='Magic')")
```

Which doesn't work, but if there's another way.

I tried the COUNTIFS but since the range is different, it also doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIFS ('SheetName'!$L:$L, "Action", 'SheetName'!$M:$BM, "Magic")
```

Perhaps a combo of Filter and COUNTIF? Combining Filter (for Action), and then countif across a range...

[sample of what the sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdLly.png)

On a separate sheet (in the same book), counting "Action" series w/ "Magic" tag would ideally turn up something like this, if there were two series tagged with "Action" as a main genre, and then "Magic" somewhere in one of the tag columns:

[sample of potential output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnH3o.png)

Link to [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuhoWCrM06eMOMwrQfKZ2PMNDTbQeUsaLP9Y98f2Tes/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you!!

Comment: Totally do-able. But the most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it) here, being sure to set the link's permission (when you create it) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always easier by far to develop solutions when one has access to the actual data. However, "eyeing it," I've created a formula you can try:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("~"&L2:BM&"~")," ",COLUMNS(L2:BM))),"~Action~.+~Magic~"))))`

Let's make sure it works as expected  before I invest the time into explanations.

If this doesn't work as expected, please share a link to a copy of the sheet, being sure to set the permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Tried that one and looks like it's only returning "0" :( I've added a sample sheet now! The first sheet is where the tags are, and second sheet is where I would like to draw the counts on! thank you so much https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuhoWCrM06eMOMwrQfKZ2PMNDTbQeUsaLP9Y98f2Tes/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). The formula in my post works; it appears you just didn't know how to adapt it to your layout, so I've adapted it to your sample. You'll see it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following `query` method to count with specific condition:

**Single query method**

```
=QUERY(A:E,"Select Count(B) where B='Action' And C='Magic' Or B='Action' And D='Magic' Or B='Action' And E='Magic'")
```

To return the value of `magic` is simple, but unable to wrap together with the query above:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"Select C where C='Magic'")
```

The sample data:

[image]

**Join Query method**

Or return in single line with `transpose` and `third query`:

```
=query({TRANSPOSE({QUERY(A:C,"Select C where C='Magic'")
;QUERY(A:E,"Select Count(B) where B='Action' And C='Magic' Or B='Action' And D='Magic' Or B='Action' And E='Magic'")})},"Select Col1, Col3")
```

[image]